# Trigger method in caller class

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview, static-methods

Hello,
I have an application that needs to call a method from the class that called the new class.
To be specific, i have a class that is an activity and inside that class i called the `surfaceView` class that i have implemented.

I now want to call the `startActivity(intent)` when something in the surfaceView occurs.

Since i cannot call another activity from the `surfaceView` i want to call a method in the class that called the `sufaceView` class.

So far i have tried something like:

```
public void startActivity() {
    Start.lose();
}
```

Wheres Start is the caller class and i have added like `import com.example.Start;` and the lose method i called like so:

```
public static void lose(){
    c.startActivity(new Intent(c,GameOver.class));
}
```

Wheres c is the context ( applicationContext to be specific ). I had to do so because this method is `static`  and this is the only way to call an activity from a static method, but it crashes and does not give any errors in the `logcat`.

Any suggestions to what i can do here?

Okay my `logcat` was bugged, now i get the error message:

```
07-14 14:42:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(13111): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-115
07-14 14:42:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(13111): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException:  Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
07-14 14:42:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(13111):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:856)
07-14 14:42:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(13111):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
07-14 14:42:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(13111):    at com.example.fishtruck.Start.lose(Start.java:92)
07-14 14:42:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(13111):    at com.example.fishtruck.GameView.startActivity(GameView.java:314)
07-14 14:42:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(13111):    at com.example.fishtruck.GameView$GameThread.lose(GameView.java:227)
07-14 14:42:43.545: E/AndroidRuntime(13111):    at com.example.fishtruck.GameView$GameThread.run(GameView.java:208)
```

Comment: Crashes with no log?? Not possible

Comment: Check it out now, i had a problem with logcat

Comment: Its clear that you need to set flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK while starting activity.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to find how to do so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like so:

```
c.startActivity(new Intent(c,GameOver.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Thanks to Kumar for helping me.